# equivalence relation/ equivalence classes/quotient space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

We define a relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\mathbin{/}$ $\{0,0\}$ by chosing two points $p, q \in {\mathbb{R}²}$, if they are on the same line, where the line has to go through the origin (0,0). Show that $\sim$ is a equivalence relation and define its quotient space and the equivalence classes.

---

So each line that goes through the origine can be written as $y=m \cdot x$, so if we choose $m$ arbitrarily but fixed than each point which lies on this line has to fulfill $y_{p}=m \cdot x_{p} $. showing reflexivity and transitivity and symmetry is not a problem here, however I do not know what the equivalence classes and the quotient space would be?

Comment: The equivalence classes will be "*the different lines*"... the space being isomorphic to an interval like $[0,\pi)$ (*in reference to the angles*), or the upper half of the unit circle, or however you like to describe it.

Comment: Just like JMoravitz said, the equivalence class determined by $x\in\Bbb{R}^2$ is the set $\{y|y\sim x\}$. In your case, this set is equivalent to a line that goes through the origin (different classes are different lines). Now, since each line can be determined by using the closed upper half plane, we conclude that the quotient space is equivalent to the closed upper half unit circle with $(-1,0)\sim (1,0)$ because they're on $y=0x$.

Comment: Topologically, the quotient is a circle, not an arc, right?

Comment: @Kevin.S thank you, I understand it now, could you tell me how I could write the equivalnce classes and quotient space formally?

Comment: What do mean by "define its quotient space"?

Comment: @PaulFrost In exercises regarding equivalence relations it is often asked to define the respective equivalence classes and the quotient space (Hope I understood your question correctly)

Comment: @GerryMyerson .Yes. Homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: @Parinn The quotient space is the set of all equivalence classes with the quotient topology.  Thus, if you know the equivalence classes, then you also know the quotient space. But this is a very abstract decription and does not tell you what is *really* looks like. In your question one can show that the quotient space is *homeomorphic* to a circle - but that is not completely trivial. So you should explain what you expect. In its present form your question does not make much sense.

Comment: @Parinn Well, the formal definition of equivalence class (according what I learned) uses the set notation, which I mentioned in my last comment. I think it's ok to use that to denote an equivalence class.